# Help with Test Class: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: failing-tests, null-pointer

My apex consists of an trigger and an apex class. My test class continues to fail with `System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object`

Trigger:

```
trigger PQ_Update on ProdQueue__c (after update) 
{    
    Set<ID> ids = Trigger.newMap.keySet();
    List<ProdQueue__c> pq = [SELECT Id, Listing__c, Listing__r.id, Status__c, OM_Approve__c, Producer__c FROM ProdQueue__c WHERE id in :ids];
    system.debug('pq');
    if(pq.size()>0){
        PQ_Update.updatePQ(pq);
    }
}
```

Apex:

```
public class PQ_Update 
{
    public static void updatePQ(List<ProdQueue__c> pq)
    { 
        List<Listing__c> ls= new list<Listing__c>();
        for(ProdQueue__c i : pq)
        {
            ls.add(i.Listing__r);
            for (Listing__c l : ls)
            {
                l.Producer__c=i.Producer__c;
                l.Production_Status__c=i.Status__c;             
                l.OM_Approve__c=i.OM_Approve__c;                  
            }
        }    
        update ls;
    }
}
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest
public class PQ_UpdateTEST {
     public static testMethod void updatePQ(){
        Property__c pro = new Property__c();
        insert pro;        

        Listing__c l = new Listing__c (
            Name = 'Test Name',
            Already_Converted__c = 'Not Converted',
            Property__c = pro.id,
            Probability__c = 50,
            Sale_Price__c = 8888888888.00,
            Commission_Input__c = 9999.99,
            Asking_Price__c = 1777777777,
            Down_Payment__c = 55555555,
            Mortgage_Amount__c = 444444,
            Occupancy_at_Close__c = 333,
            Transaction_Notes__c = 'TEST TEST',
            Close_Date__c = date.Today(),
            CAP_Rate__c = 9.99,
            Sale_Price_SF__c = 25,
            Lease_Expiration_Date__c = date.Today()
        );
        insert l;

        List<ProdQueue__c> pqList = new List<ProdQueue__c>();
        ProdQueue__c pqOne = new ProdQueue__c(
            Listing__c=l.id,
            Status__c='OM Complete',
            OM_Approve__c='Yes',
            Producer__c='Brian',
            Production_Type__c='OM'
        );

        ProdQueue__c pqTwo = new ProdQueue__c(
            Listing__c=l.id,
            Status__c='OM Complete',
            OM_Approve__c='Yes',
            Producer__c='Brian',
            Production_Type__c='OM'
        );


        pqList.add(pqOne);
        pqList.add(pqTwo);

        insert pqList;

        PQ_Update.updatePQ(pqList);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line are you getting the null pointer exception?

Comment: l.Production_Status__c=i.Status__c;

Comment: code coverage also stops here

Comment: Why are you directly calling `PQ_Update.updatePQ(pqList);` in your test method when it should just be called through the trigger?  And why are you re-querying the ProdQueue__c records in your trigger?

Comment: What happens if you replace your whole trigger with `PQ_Update.updatePQ(trigger.new);` ?

Comment: the only reason I can see for requerying is to get parent or child objects, but the only parent reference is `Listing__r.id` which is the same as `Listing__c` and that will be available in the Trigger context

Comment: I was following this: `https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_bestpract.htm`

But after re-reading it, it looks like it's not appropriate in this situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd rewrite this as follows:

**Trigger**

```
trigger PQ_Update on ProdQueue__c (after update) {
    PQ_Update.updatePQ(Trigger.new);
}
```

**Handler class**

```
public class PQ_Update {
    public static void updatePQ(List<ProdQueue__c> pqs) {
        map<ID,Listing__c> lIdToListingMap= new map<ID,Listing__c>();
        for(ProdQueue__c pq : pqs) {
            if (pq.listing__c != null)
               lIdToListingMap.put(pq.listing__c,new Listing__c(
                                   id = pq.listing__c,
                                   Producer__c=pq.Producer__c,
                                   Production_Status__c=pq.Status__c,             
                                   OM_Approve__c=pq.OM_Approve__c));                 
        }    
        update lIdToListingMap.values();
    }
}
```

Based on your test class, you are copying values from PQs into parent `Listing__c`. Since the trigger has a reference to the parent, you can construct the sobject to be updated from the reference ID `Listing__c`. No extra SOQL required and no double loops. Also, if two PQs happen to point at the same `Listing__c`, then the last one in the trigger set will be the 'winner` when it comes to updating the parent Listing. If this is not what you want, the logic needs to get more sophisticated.

I'd also strongly consider renaming the handler method `updatePQ` to be something like `afterUpdateHandler` that in turn calls a method `enhanceListings` or something indicative of the business purpose of this little snippet - since you may have other snippets to add over time that need to be executed when a PQ is updated

And, your testmethod needs asserts to verify that the code does what you expect

Comment: Thank you! Working great. I haven't used the map methods before...wasn't sure when the appropriate time was to use them, I'll read over the documentation on them now.

Comment: @MRG if you spend enough time on this forum and study enough of the answers, you'll see that SFDC actually designed Apex to do common things in a fairly concise way - but that the doc doesn't always make these idioms clear.  Glad I could help